# Print linked list up to specific number in C

Tags: c, for-loop, linked-list, singly-linked-list, function-definition

Suppose I have a linked list of unknown length. I would like to have a function to print out whole list if the length is less than 10, and if its length more than 10, then display only first 10 nodes.

However, because I'm comparing the pointer and integer to print out first 10 nodes, I'm getting the following error:

```
ordered comparison between pointer and integer ('NodeT *' (aka 'struct node *') and 'int')
        for (current = list; current < 30; current = current->next)
```

If I change it to have a count and loop while count is less than 10, I'm getting a segmentation fault.

How can I display first 10 nodes if list is length is more than 10?

I have the following function:

```
void *printNodes(NodeT *list) {
    
    int length = countNodes(list); // finds length of a linked list
    int count = 0; 

    NodeT *current;

    if (list == NULL) {
        printf("Empty list.\n");
    }

    if (length < 10) {
        // Display all if number of nodes is less than 10
        for (current = list; current != NULL; current = current->next) {
            printf("%s\n", current->data); 
        }

    } else {
        // Display first 10 if number of nodes more than 10 
        for (current = list; current < 10; current = current->next) {
            printf("%s\n", current->data);

        // for (current = list; count < 10; current = current->next) {
        //     printf("%s\n", current->data);
        //     count++; 

        }
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: *I'm comparing the pointer and integer*. So don't do it. Why would you think that could work in any way? Use a seperate counter instead to compare with `10`. Or you could even use `length` directly by decrementing it til it gets to `0`.

Comment: Run it with your debugger which will tell you _where_ exactly the segfauklt happens. Invest some time to learn the debugger. Believe me, the time invested will very quickly pay off.

Comment: Then you need to show a [complete minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Maybe `countNodes` is wrong. Maybe the list is incorrectly formed. We can't tell with such incomplete code.

Comment: The code that you commented out looks correct to me. Therefore, if that code gives you a segmentation fault, then I suspect that either (1) the function `countNodes` (which you are not showing) is providing incorrect information, or (2) `current->data` is not always pointing to a valid null-terminated string, or (3) the linked list itself is corrupt. Since you did not provide a [mre], we have no way of knowing.

Answer (score 3):

For starters the return type `void *` of the function `printNodes`

```
void *printNodes(NodeT *list) {
```

does not make a sense.

You should declare the function at least like

```
void printNodes( const NodeT *list) {
```

As the number of potentially outputted nodes is known there is no need to determine how many nodes there are in the list.

If the condition of this if statement

```
if (list == NULL) {
    printf("Empty list.\n");
}
```

evaluates to the logical true the function shall return.

The condition of the for loop where a pointer is compared with an integer

```
    for (current = list; current < 10; current = current->next) {
```

does not make a sense.

The function can be declared and defined the following way.

```
void printNodes( const NodeT *list ) 
{
    size_t n = 10;
    
    if ( list == NULL ) 
    {
        printf("Empty list.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        for ( ; list != NULL && n--; list = list->next )
        {
            printf( "%s\n", list->data );
        }
    }
}
```

Another approach is to declare one more parameter that will specify how many nodes of the list you want to output. For example

```
void printNodes( const NodeT *list, size_t n ) 
{
    if ( list == NULL ) 
    {
        printf("Empty list.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        for ( ; list != NULL && n--; list = list->next )
        {
            printf( "%s\n", list->data );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider adapting your main `for` loop to serve as a counter:

```c
void printNodes(NodeT *list) {
  if (list == NULL) {
    printf("Empty list.\n");

    return; // Note no more useless "pointer" return
  }

  int limit = 10; // Could easily be an argument
  NodeT *current = list;

  for (int i = 0; current && i < limit; ++i, current = current->next) {
      printf("%s\n", current->data);
  }
}
```

The key here is you need to test that *both* the pointer is valid and the counter hasn't tripped.

In your adaptation you walked off the end of the chain without paying attention to your `current` pointer.

Comment: I'm getting the following warning - `incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'int' with an expression of type 'NodeT *' (aka 'struct node *') for (int i = 0, current = list; current && i < 30; i++, current = current->next) {`

Comment: I've adapted the code to be more consistent. The issue was using the `int` declaration erroneously where the `,` operator couldn't cope.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the `else` part in this way:

```
for (current = list; count< 10; count++, current = current->next)
    ///your code
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for loop as mentioned by [tadman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65908748/10537101) or a while loop like this

```
int counter = 0;
NodeT *current = list;
while (counter < 10 && current != NULL)
{
  /* Do your stuff */
  current = current->next;
  counter += 1;
}
```

Instead of finding the length of the linked list as you did, which might make the time complexity of your function linear, you just need to check if the counter is at most ten and if the current node is not null.